# Robot Framework custom keyword only in Test Setup

Tags: python, robotframework

Is there a possibility in Robot Framework to **allow executing a custom keyword only in Test Setup** part (or alternatively in Test Teardown)? Assuming that I have a keyword called `My Setup`. If `My Setup` is executed in a normal step (i.e. not in Test Setup), the test should fail. RF Documentation about [User keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-user-keywords) and browsing through StackOverflow didn't give me any meaningful results.

For example, the documentation in Robot Framework's built-in function `Run keyword if all tests passed` states that "Trying to use it anywhere else results in an error", so I was wondering that there should be some kind of way to apply this for custom keywords, too.

I have tried to fix this by parsing the test file before starting the test execution and checking for any occurences of `My Setup` that are not in Test Setup. This, however, feels very cumbersome, so what I'm looking for is something like following:

```
def MySetup(self, some_arg):
    if MAGIC.not_inside_test_setup():
        raise AssertionError('"My Setup" can be executed only in Test Setup')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue with a help from a colleague. The solution was the following:

Assuming that `My Setup` keyword is defined in library called `My Library`.

1. Use a Listener to check when the custom keyword `My Setup` is executed by the help of listener method called `start_keyword`. The method contains information whether the keyword is executed as a regular keyword or as a Test Setup/Teardown keyword.
2. If `My Setup` is run as not-test-setup keyword, in the listener a global error flag inside `My Library` should be set through an instance of `My Library`
3. At the beginning of the execution of `My Setup`, check if the global error flag in `My Library` is set; raise an error if set.

MyLibrary.py

```
SETUP_ERROR = None

class MyLibrary(object):

    def MySetup(self, some_arg):
        global SETUP_ERROR

        if SETUP_ERROR:
            raise AssertionError(SETUP_ERROR)

        # Otherwise continue with the setup

    def _SetError(self, error):
        global SETUP_ERROR
        SETUP_ERROR = error
```

Listener.py

```
from MyLibrary import MyLibrary

class MyListener(object):
    # ...
    def start_keyword(self, name, attributes):
        if name == 'MyLibrary.My Setup' and attributes['type'] != 'Setup':
            MyLibrary()._SetError('"My Setup" can be executed only in Test Setup')
```

Comment: You can combine the listener and keyword library into a single file -- keyword libraries can also be listeners. See [Test libraries as listeners](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-listeners)

Comment: @BryanOakley Good point and useful especially if only e.g. `start_keyword` would be needed in the listener. However, in my case, the `My Library` is already bloating, so separating them was intentional.